# Avoid subscribeNext be called at subscription time

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am doing the following code:

```
[RACObserve(obj, property) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"property was changed");
}];
obj.property = @"bla";
```

This code call the block twice, one at subscription time and one when the property is modified. I want the block be called only when the property is modified. Is there any way this behavior can be avoided with reactivecocoa?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-skip:` operator to prevent the subscriber from getting called with the property's initial value.

Comment: can you describe a little more details about how to use -skip? I can not find related document. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to the [header documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/ee85a34731382b01ea028026ef267b0952b7edde/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L177-L182). To skip the first value, do something like `[signal skip:1]`.